# How do I prevent react-navigation from showing a transition animation during StackAction.reset?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-stack

Using react-navigation-stack 1.10.3, resetting StackActions loads the new stack in place without a transition. The same code snippet with react-navigation-stack 2.0.15 adds a platform default transition, which for iOS is SlideFromRightIOS.

How do I replicate the previous behavior on 1.10.X with 2.0.X where there is no transition while the stack gets reset?

```js
navigation.dispatch(
    StackActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({
                routeName: user ? 'Home' : 'Landing',
            }),
        ],
    }),
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable animation for these screens by adding `animationEnabled: false` in the `navigationOptions` of your `Home` and `Landing` screens.

```js
Home.navigationOptions = {
  animationEnabled: false
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, @satya164 It would be really great if there is a way to disable animation for the "from-route", not the one you're moving to.